# Do I use a break to escape the loop or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Tags: c#

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    string strCurrentString = textBoxInput.Text.Trim().ToString();
    if (strCurrentString != "")
    {
        if (radioButtonPick.Checked == true && radioButtonNew.Checked == true)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in excelviewgrid.Rows)
            {
                if (strCurrentString == row.Cells["Material"].Value.ToString())
                {
                    int value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxmultiply.Text);
                    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
                    {
                        listBoxinput.Items.Add(textBoxInput.Text + " | " + row.Cells["Material Description"].Value + " (-1 New Pick)");
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Article");
                }
            }
        }
        comboBoxmultiply.SelectedIndex = 0;
        textBoxInput.Clear();
    }
}
```

At the moment the MessageBox from the else statement always triggers no matter whether the if statement is true or false and is stuck on the screen. I presume because of the foreach loop. How do I solve this in a good way? Do I just `break;` after the else statement? Multiple breaks? Or different code?

Comment: Put a breakpoint (F9) in that method, run your app (F5) and inspect that string and that row value. Observe what happens when you step through thecode (F10). Note that now for every row a decision is made whether to display that message

Comment: This is great info for the future so i can search for the problem myself. altough i kinda already expected it was the foreach loop and i don't know how to solve that issue.

Comment: Showing an example of the data would help here, and a better description of what you are trying to achieve. I think Tim's answer is the right one, is there only going to be a simple row in the table that matches the `textBoxInput`?

Comment: its an excel file that gets loading in by the user to a datagridview. it has 3 columns "Material" "Material description" and "Stock".

I then have a textbox ,a combobox and a listbox.

the user inputs the "material" into the textbox and selects a 1-30 value from the combobox then presses enter. it then has to check if that material exists on the datagridview. if it does it inputs that value with the material description and some hardcodes text 

listBoxinput.Items.Add(textBoxInput.Text + " | " + row.Cells["Material Description"].Value + " (-1 New Pick)");

if the check fails->show msg

Comment: on top of that i have mulltiple radiobuttons that the user has to check before it does all that but all that works fine. i just need the check fail = msg that doesn't get stuck looping inside the foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not loop all grid-rows and show a MessageBox everytime that it was not the material you searched. Instead first loop all rows and show the message-box afterwards. And yes, use `break` to exit the loop if you have found the row.

You could use code like this:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    AddMaterialsToListBox(textBoxInput.Text.Trim(), Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxmultiply.Text));
    comboBoxmultiply.SelectedIndex = 0;
    textBoxInput.Clear();
}
```

// .....

```
void AddMaterialsToListBox(string materialName, int count)
{
    DataGridViewRow materialRow = null;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in excelviewgrid.Rows)
    {
        if (materialName == row.Cells["Material"].Value.ToString())
        {
            materialRow = row;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(materialRow == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Article");
        return;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        listBoxinput.Items.Add(materialName + " | " + materialRow.Cells["Material Description"].Value + " (-1 New Pick)");
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this code it does look way cleaner then whatever mine was but could you like explain the flow of the code of what does what. if it is not too much trouble ofcourse.

Your code works perfectly fine btw.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, isn't the code self explanatory? Then i did something wrong. It basically provides a method for what you want to do: add n-material items to the ListBox. This method needs 2 parameters: the name of the material and the count. Then it tries to search that material in the grid. If it's not found the MessageBox is shown and the method is exited. Otherwise it will add the ListBox items.

Answer (score 1):

`break` is the simplest solution, but we need a flag or some other variable to determine that the loop completed due to the break, and not due to the loop completing normally:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    string strCurrentString = textBoxInput.Text.Trim().ToString();
    if (strCurrentString != "")
    {
        if (radioButtonPick.Checked == true && radioButtonNew.Checked == true)
        {
            bool found = false;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in excelviewgrid.Rows)
            {
                if (strCurrentString == row.Cells["Material"].Value.ToString())
                {
                    found = true;
                    int value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxmultiply.Text);
                    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
                    {
                        listBoxinput.Items.Add(textBoxInput.Text + " | " + row.Cells["Material Description"].Value + " (-1 New Pick)");
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found)
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Article");
        }
        comboBoxmultiply.SelectedIndex = 0;
        textBoxInput.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst I have directly addressed the post, I think this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73352292/1690217 is a better understanding of the actual intent that OP had not directly expressed. In there the `null` state of the found record _is the flag_.

Comment: i tried your first code but it would still show the messagebox on a correct value.

It will always go over the else code even if value is true because of the foreach loop so success will always be false. so the message box will always pop up.

Comment: I have updated this, however it was @Tim-Schmelter who correctly identified you actual intent first

Comment: Your code however does also solve the problem, while using my mess of a code.